# Card Slide Gallery in UIViewController

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, swift5, uiswipegesturerecognizer

Is there a way to implement a card sliding gallery in a UIViewController? The gallery is not supposed to have images but buttons. I'm thinking the app "Bumble" for example when it comes to their subscription process. You can swipe through 2 cards to choose your subscription model. This has to be implemented in a UIViewController .. Any chance to get this done?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try using UICollectionView to emulate how bumble cardview works

make the scroll direction to horizontal and disable the scroll indicator

and then, add  UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout protocol and use these two bad boys

```
    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        
    }

    func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
        
    }
```

what the two of them do is detect when the scroll gesture is decelerating and end of the scroll gesture. You can try to engineered the movement

here's an example how I implement it

```
    private lazy var collectionView:UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        //layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 330, height: 150)
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 20, bottom: 0, right: 20)
        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 70, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 150),collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell2")
        collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .clear
        return collectionView
    }()
```

delegate :

```
    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        self.collectionView.scrollToNearestVisibleCollectionViewCell()
    }

    func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
        if !decelerate {
            self.collectionView.scrollToNearestVisibleCollectionViewCell()
        }
    }
```

Comment: for the whole page, it's either tableview and one of the cell has collectionView in it or advance level collectionView in which supports ios14+

Comment: the switches functionality i believe comes from the UIcollectionView delegate, try to learn it too if possible

Comment: thank you ! but unfortunately not working on my end ...